# Android merge two images

Tags: android

I have these two images, which I basically merge on canvas. Now i want to save that canvas into an image. How should i do it or if there is any other way to merge two images.

My sample code is  -

```
            Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.duckpic);
        Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.img);
        // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        // canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, 10, 10, null);
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp2.getWidth(), bmp2
                .getHeight(), bmp2.getConfig());
        // Canvas cs = new Canvas(bmp2);
        canvas.scale((float) 0.5, (float) 0.5);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.save();
```

I got it working by doing this -

```
    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, new Matrix(), null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, new Matrix(), null);
    comboImage.save();
    // this is an extra bit I added, just incase you want to save the new
    // image somewhere and then return the location

    String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";

    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + tmpImg);
        cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e);
    }
```

Basically it is given here - http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas

Comment: http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2012/08/mearge-images.html refer this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [canvas.setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29).  This will send the canvas to the specified Bitmap.  You'll want to create a new, mutable bitmap for this.  After you call `setBitmap` you can then save that Bitmap to a file.