# AndEngine Merging Sprites

Tags: sprite, andengine, frame-rate, blending

I have been tackling a severe performance issue with an AndEngine powered live wallpaper for a while now (I've posted another question about it a while back, before I knew what was causing it at all), and it seems that the only way to get this to work properly is to merge a few sprites together.

I have a half dozen or so fairly large sprites, all the same size, that get layered directly on top of each other.  I do it this way so it all looks like one image, but each part of it can be set to a different color via code whenever I'd like.  For some reason or other, layering sprites when using a blending mode that utilizes alpha at all (Even if there wasn't any alpha in the images) does some major damage to your frame rate, and I can't find any simple way around this.

The solution I've arrived at is that I will need to do what I need to with the sprites individually, and then merge them together into one.  I've spent quite a few hours diving into various classes of AndEngine, trying not to destroy anything in the process, but I just cannot figure out how to do it.

I'm certain that it cannot be **that** difficult to slap one sprite onto another, or putting the re-worked sprites back into a temporary texture atlas somehow, I just can't quite grasp how to get it going.

**EDIT ::**

```
    public void onLoadResources(){
    this.mTestAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 1024, TextureOptions.NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(layer1);
    Bitmap a =  overlay(b);
    test = new BitmapTextureAtlasSource(a);

    this.mTesting = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(this.mTestAtlas, test, 0, 0);

    this.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTestAtlas);      
}   

public Scene onLoadScene(){
    layer1Sprite = new Sprite(x, y, width, height, this.mTesting);
    scene.attachChild(layer1Sprite);
}

public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);

    Paint layer1Paint = new Paint();
    ColorFilter layer1Filter;
    layer1Filter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.rgb(175, 0, 175), 1);
    layer1Paint.setColorFilter(layer1Filter);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp4, 0, 0, layer1Paint);

   return bmOverlay;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Andengine does not provide any tools or methods to do this, but fortunately, native Android does. Here is an article that shows how to make a function that inputs two bitmaps but outputs one, merged bitmap.

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas
There is a related question here:
[Android merge two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129520/android-merge-two-images)

**Update for Andengine GLES2:**

AS of December 2011, there is a new version of Andrengine called Andengine GLES2. It has a built in resource for drawing your andengine sprites into a textures. Here is teh release note:

> **RenderToTexture/RenderTexture**
>
> **Usage:**
>
> **Render something into a Texture and use that texture for Sprites. (i.e. useful when rendering some complex mesh once and then efficiently drawing it again as a sprite.)
> Post-Processing effects**

And the link to the original forum post outlining additions to GLES2.

http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/andengine-gles2-pre-release-on-december-23rd-t6097.html

Comment: I had tried something similar before with no results, but after looking at the links you gave and browsing around to find a few more I have managed to get it going.  It actually seems to work great, but I have one strange problem yet.  Sprites that are created this way disappear off of the screen when it is resumed, like coming from another app or turning the phone back on.  It seems a little weird to me, but I am sure there's a simple reason for it.

Comment: I suspect your images are getting garbage collected. It might be a good idea to write those images to file so that they can be restored if android kills the activity. Maybe post your code?

Comment: I added a trimmed down version of my setup.  Sorry for my very poor structure and naming, I intend to fix the code up proper when I get this sorted out.  I removed any stuff that was just repeats of what is already there (I am combining multiple images, thus the need for that "Overlay" method).  If I missed something that should've been included I'll be happy to post it up.  It does seem you are correct about it being garbage collection, just based on a quick look.  Is there a way to just tell the GC not to touch it, or would saving it out as an image be the best way to handle it?