# Set tick mark at image in gridview when answered correctly

Tags: java, android, image, gridview

I am trying to make an app similar to the Logo quiz's, but in stead of guessing the logos, you get to see a part of a car and you have to guess which car it is. I have listed the car pictures in a gridview and when you click it you can enter your answer. This all works fine. When you have given the correct answer, this is saved to an SQLite database. So now my question is: How can i show a tick mark or green outline etc. in the gridview, only at the pictures you have answered correctly? If a picture has been answered correctly already, a string with "YES" is inserted under the column "Correct" in the database. Here is what i have so far:

```
private void checkDB() {
    try{
        DbHelper entry = new DbHelper (Main.this);
        entry.openDataBase();
        Cursor c = entry.getInfo();
//Check everything at the "Correct" column
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            String correct = c.getString(1);

        if (correct.equals("YES")){
//If it has been answered correctly get it's id
            int id = c.getInt(0);
//Add the tick mark at the specific picture
            gridView.?????
        }
        else{

        }
            entry.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

I am really unexperienced at programming, so i hope you understand what i mean ;) Please help!

Comment: Check this link http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas it was also shared on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129520/android-merge-two-images it worked for me for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the position of the clicked image by making the position final and adding an onClick listener to the imageView.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ImageView imageView;
 if (convertView == null) {  
// if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(10, 8, 10, 8);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.d("onClick","position ["+position+"]");
  }

});
} 
 else 
{
 imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
}
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the point is that you should see the tick mark when you open the gridview  in stead of after you have clicked. That way the user can see that they have completed that image already. This tick mark needs to be on top of each correctly answered image in the gridview. I hope you understand it.