# how to change images without change the background image

Tags: android, imageview, gestures

I have six image-button with gallery .when i click on first button the background images are appeared in scroll-view . After i click i any button i m select image from gallery and set on background image..after that i want to merge them on single!

This is my background image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxEpQ.png

### and i set this image on background image.i onclick on this button then this types of images are appeared.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cb0z.png

### both images are i m selecting from different gallery.

Comment: make your parent as relative layout and then add each image over it.

Comment: Look at this topic, maybe it helps.

[Merge two images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129520/android-merge-two-images)

Answer (score 1):

image Masking is good way for merging two images.and convert it one bitmap image then set into single imageview.

Answer (score 0):

set first image to background and change android drawble top image  dynamically .
see following code xml file code.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="openNewApplication"
        android:background="@drawable/apj_kalam"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/rect"/>
```

Comment: but sir background image should be anything.it also selected from gallery which are apeared by default on scrollview